# instantaneous digit input in c

Tags: c

i want to take a very long integer(it may contain upto 1000 digits). and i want to store it in an array so that each digit will sit in each place of the array.but if i try to use the code below it takes the whole number in the 0 position untill i press enter. but i can't press enter. each digit will be scanned separately even though the user will write it as a complete number.

```
for(count=0;number[count]!='\0';count++){
            scanf("%d",number+count);
        }
```

what is the way there??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `scanf`. Use `fgets` to get a line of input as a `char*`, then you can pull individual digits out of the `char*` as characters, and convert them to `int` digits yourself. `scanf("%d", ...)` will cause problems if the user enters input that can't be parsed as a digit.

```
char *inputLine = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_DIGITS + 1);
fgets(inputLine, MAX_DIGITS, stdin); // or replace stdin with a FILE *
```

`fgets` will consume the entire line of input up to the newline, or stop at the number of characters specified by argument 2.

If you want to continue reading digit-by-digit, then use `getchar()` to read individual characters, or `fgetc(FILE *)` to read individual characters from a file.

```
char *inputLine = malloc(sizof(char) * (MAX_DIGITS + 1));
char ch = getchar();
int i = 0;
while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF) && (i < MAX_DIGITS))
{
    inputLine[i++] = ch;
    ch = getchar();
}
```

Comment: i get you. thanks. but isn't there any simpler way that will just read digit by digit??

Comment: use `getchar`. You can use `scanf("%c")` but you might as well use `getchar` for individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` reads an integer - if you want to read one character at a time, use `%c`, or alternately replace your `scanf()` call with [`getchar(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar).

Comment: if you want to read one character at a time, use %c- it doesn't work. i guess you meant this..


char a[50],k;
    for(k=0;a[k]!='\0';k++){
        scanf("%c",&a[k]);
    }
    printf("%d",k);

Comment: I don't know what that means, but `%c` definitely works to read one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char number[SIZE];
int nDigits = 0;

printf("Write a number: ");
while ((number[nDigits] = getchar()) != '\n') nDigits++;

printf("The number is: %s\n", number);
```

Also, be aware that you might need to fill the `number` array / string with zeros.